# What is the address of my Flash debugger?

Tags: flash, ipad, ios, flash-cs5, pfi

I packaged my SWF for iPad and exported to debug. I installed the .ipa on my iPad. When I tapped on the icon, nothing happened for a few minutes. Then, I got a UIAlertView asking for the address of my Flash debugger.

Does anyone know what that address might be, or what to do with that UIAlertView?

Comment: i'm certain there is no Flash Debugger on iOS.  are there any breakpoints in your code?  try deleting all ASO files and repackage.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that there are no breakpoints. When I package for testing, an not debugging it plays, but when I package for debugging it does not. (Note that some of my movieclips don't appear on the stage as they should.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [Adobe's website](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/WS789ea67d3e73a8b2780918df124b3c90179-8000.html), I've found the answer:

> Debugging the application on the
>   iPhone To debug the application on the
>   iPhone:
>
> Compile the application with debug
>   support: In Flash Professional CS5,
>   compile using the “Quick publishing
>   for device debugging” setting. (See
>   Creating an iPhone application
>   installer file using the Packager for
>   iPhone included with in Flash
>   Professional CS5.) Using the PFI
>   command-line application, compile the
>   application with the target ipa-debug
>   option. (See Creating an iPhone
>   application installer file from the
>   command line.) Install the application
>   on the iPhone. On the iPhone, turn
>   Wi-Fi on and connect to the same
>   network as that of the development
>   computer. Start a debug session on
>   your development computer. In Flash
>   Professional CS5, choose Debug > Begin
>   Remote Debug Session > ActionScript
>   3.0. Run the application on the iPhone. The debug version of the
>   application will prompt you for the IP
>   address of the developer computer.
>   Enter the IP address and tap the OK
>   button. To obtain the IP address of
>   the development computer. On Mac OS,
>   on the Apple menu, choose System
>   Preference. In the System Preferences
>   window, click the Network icon. The
>   Network preferences window lists the
>   IP address. On Windows, start a
>   command-line session and run the
>   ipconfig command.

Comment: ipa-debug was a keyword for me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try switching the user agent of your browser to iOS and testing it that way using a SWF? I'm not sure I understand your issue.

Comment: I packaged the app as an ipa and installed it on the iPad. See the edit to my question.