# AIR mobile debug - "Enter ip address or hostname"

Tags: ios, flash, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I'm developing a mobile app using Flash Builder 4.6/AIR. I've been able to debug on the device (an iPhone 4s) just fine until now. I connect my iPhone to my mac with the USB corad, and debug.

All of a sudden I'm getting a black screen for close to a minute. Then I see the "Enter ip address or hostname" dialog. If I enter the ip address of my machine it doesn't matter. The window goes away for about 15 seconds, then comes back. Meanwhile, Flash Builder on my mac times out. The only way I can actually see the program running is if I hit 'Cancel' on that dialog. The app then launches, but I cannot set any breakpoints, cannot debug.

Everything I've found on the internet around this issue mentions it in reference to AIR for android -- not iOs. But I'm seeing it with iOs.

Anyone know what's going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: Have your network settings changed? If you're asked to enter the debugger's IP, the device usually can't find your machine. Not sure if you know this, but other than Android, iOS debugging does not work via USB. USB is just used to push your debug app to the device, the debugging itself (to be specific the connection between debugger and device) uses your local network, so make sure both devices are in the same network.

Comment: @Al_Birdy -- yes, that's it. If you resubmit this as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: See also [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162180/what-is-the-address-of-my-flash-debugger][1]
That question and answer helped me much more than this.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162180/what-is-the-address-of-my-flash-debugger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it easier for future readers, the official answer to this issue;

With the current (official) version of the AIR SKD (3.2) USB debugging is not supported on iOS devices. This is going to change with the future 3.3 release which (amongst others) adds USB debugging support:

"**USB debugging for AIR iOS** 
This new feature allows the iOS developer to connect to the desktop via USB while debugging their mobile applications instead of relying on network connectivity."

With version 3.2, iOS debugging works over the local network, so both devices (the machine the debugger runs on and the iOS device) have to be in the same network so that they can communicate with each other.

Comment: I am running AIR 3.3, and just recently the debug stopped working, experiencing the same problem as David (initial post). Though you were right, I just noticed I temporarily stopped Wifi and that was what was causing the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See also the reply to [What is the address of my Flash debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162180/what-is-the-address-of-my-flash-debugger), it really helped me to resolve similar issue. Using 'ios-debug' mode was the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have this problem using Android with the device connected to same wifi, **try checking firewall rules**. In my case FlashDevelop was blocked and I didn't suspected because of updates worked perfectly.